# Advanced Filter VBA in Excel, use of OR

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I try to make advanced filter for Excel 2013 in VBA. For some specific reason I do not want to use Excel Tables.

I created two rows of headers: (row 48) for one with several rows with criteria (A49:Q55), and another header (row 56) for rows with data.

When I try to use the filter to use **OR** criteria, so i want to filter both values from data range, I put data in one cell in criteria range below header and other data in the second row below this cell than I receive only data that corresponds only to the first cell below header. What did go terribly wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A49:Q55")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("A56").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A48").CurrentRegion
End If

End Sub
```